# Symfony2 storing requests in object

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building API with fosRest bundle.

The method where I'm stuck looks like:

```
public function postUser(Request $request)
{
}
```

I'm want handle request with `User` entity instead of `Request`, but problem if that I'm receiving params, that are not in `User` class, or have different names

What is best way to handle this request with custom object, and where store it ?

I want do that to have code autosuggest in IDE.

My idea is created Model `User` class, is enough good for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `@ParamConverter` annotation from `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle` to inject a `$user` param into your controller *based* on the request data.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Appbundle\Entity\User;

class UserController
{
    /** 
     * @ParamConverter("user", class="AppBundle:User") 
     */
    public function postUserAction(User $user)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

(Here are the symfony docs for The [SensionFrameworkExtraBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html), and specifically the [`@ParamConverter` annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html).)

By `use`-ing your `User` class, and typehinting it in the controller param, your IDE should be able to glean more about it. Different approaches are necessary for different IDEs, of course, but this gets you to a strong starting position.

As from the docs, you might want to supply some more details about just how, exactly, the framework should try to convert a parameter into an object:

> #### DoctrineConverter Options
>
> A number of options are available on the @ParamConverter or (@Entity) annotation to control behavior:
>   id: If an id option is configured and matches a route parameter, then the converter will find by the primary key. One simple `id` example, below:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @Route("/blog/{post_id}")
>  * @ParamConverter("post", options={"id" = "post_id"})
>   */
> public function showPostAction(Post $post)
> {
> }
> ```

Comment: agree is good, but I have more params than User class contains, maybe in inject User and left Request to have all remaining params there ?

`public function showPostAction(Post $post, Request $request)
{
}`

Comment: You can absolutely do that. Symfony lets you order controller method params any way you like, and always understands which is the `Request` itself, when it's typehinted like that.